# Android Studio throws an exception trying to execute an app with logback support and minSdkVersion = 17

Tags: android, logback, android-multidex

I'm writing an Android app with Android Studio 2.2.
I defined the `minSdkVersion 17` and I added the following libraries to use [logback-android](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android):

```
compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6'
compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-6'
compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.7'
```

After that, the building process works but when I try to execute on a device (virtual or real device) the process aborts with the following exception.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lch/qos/logback/classic/AsyncAppender;
```

If I define the `minSdkVersion 19` there is not any problem, the application is built and executed smoothly on the device, but, I need minSdkVersion.

You can reproduce the issue easily just creating a simple application, adding the mentioned libraries and defining the `minSdkVersion 17`.

Do you know how it could be solved?

Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATED**
Attaching the **build.gradle** file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dcsoft.multidexfailurewithlogback"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6'
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-6'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.7'
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
Adding my **MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.dcsoft.multidexfailurewithlogback;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainActivity.class);

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
}
```

Comment: please upload your buil.gradle file

Comment: clean your project from Build > Clean Project than use File > Inavlidate Cache/ Restart

Comment: Thanks brahmy but it does not work, at least on my case.

Comment: Thanks vishal. I've uploaded the file.

Comment: I think you don't need to add     `compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.7'`. It's already included in logback-android. First try commenting that line in your build.gradle.

Comment: If I remove the line `compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-6'` the `compileDebugJavaWithJavac` tasks fails with the error `Error:(3, 17) error: package org.slf4j does not exist` when I try to import `org.slf4j.Logger`.

Comment: Reading from the doc, I found that you need to add `compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'`. It will remove the error.

Comment: Thanks!! Now it works!